# Misunderstanding sub function

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'm working on a `Shiny` app that loops through an html file replacing an instance of a phrase with a different phrase relative to its position.

That is, the first time "aa" comes, I put "bluh",
the second time "aa" comes, I put "gfgf".

I have a table of all the 2nd phrases in order.

I think I'm misunderstanding the `sub` function documentation:

> The two *sub functions differ only in that sub replaces only the first
>   occurrence of a pattern whereas gsub replaces all occurrences.

But here a smallest reproducible example:

```
tt <- c("aa", "aa","bb","aa")

sub("aa","test",tt)
# [1] "test" "test" "bb"   "test"

gsub("aa","test",tt)
# [1] "test" "test" "bb"   "test"

tt
# [1] "aa" "aa" "bb" "aa"
```

I expected

```
sub("aa","test",tt)
# [1] "test" "aa" "bb"   "aa"
```

so that I could loop through and go:

```
og.list <- c("aa","cat","aa","cat","aa")

repl.list <- c("the","is","happy")

for(i in 1:3){
  og.list <- sub("aa",repl.list[i], og.list)
}
```

instead all "aa" become "the". I thought that's what gsub did, but instead it's both `sub` and `gsub`.

Thank you.

Comment: *sub replaces only the first occurrence of a pattern whereas gsub replaces all occurrences* in a given string, not a character vector. [`sub("aa", "test", "aa aa")` will yield `test aa` and `gsub` will yield `test test`](https://ideone.com/3O8E2W).

Comment: ok. So I would have to do it across two indexes essentially? 

og.index <- grep("aa",og.list)

for(i in 1:3){ 

curr.index <- og.index[i]

og.list[curr.index] <- sub("aa",repl.list[i],og.list[curr.index]) 
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want just this:

```
og.list[og.list == "aa"] <- repl.list
#[1] "the"   "cat"   "is"    "cat"   "happy"
```

Comment: And this would recycle repl.list if they weren't the same length? 
Thank you, I didn't realize such a simple answer existed. But it makes a lot of sense that this would do a perfectly parallel swap.

Comment: Yes it would recycle, though we can easily adapt the solution not to (and assign NA instead)

Answer (score -1):

```
 Thank you Wiktor^.
```

I now understand that I would need to separate each item into its own string and then sub.

```
 og.list <- c("aa","cat","aa","cat","aa"
 repl.list <- c("the","is","happy")
 og.index <- grep("aa",og.list) 

 for(i in 1:3){ 
 curr.index <- og.index[i] 
 og.list[curr.index] <- sub("aa",
                             repl.list[i],
                             og.list[curr.index])
 }
```